# Decoding a buffer in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I've got a buffer that

```
console.log(uid);
// <Buffer 04 23 81 5a 97 37 81>
console.log(uid[0]);
// 4
console.log(uid[1]);
// 35
console.log(uid.toJSON());
// [ 4, 35, 129, 90, 151, 55, 129 ]
console.log(uid.toString());
// #ï¿½Zï¿½7ï¿½
```

I need the actual ocelet array (04,23,81,5a,97,37,81) as I need to output

```
0423815a973781
```

Any help on figuring out how to parse the buffer in such a manner would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default encoding parameter to [`Buffer.toString`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) is `utf-8`. That is why you are getting the output like you mentioned in the question.

You just have to decode it with `hex` as the second parameter, like this

```
console.log(Buffer([4, 0x23, 0x81, 0x5a, 0x97, 0x37, 0x81]).toString("hex"));
// 0423815a973781
```